# Problems accessing public folder with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm a beginner when it comes to this laravel but having a hard time trying to get going. Basically I've installed laravel but I have a problem when it comes to accessing the public folder. I'm using MAMP and currently have my laravel folder inside htdocs

```
//Applications/MAMP/htdocs/learning-laravel
```

I've given permissions to the folder 'public' (chmod 777 public) and 'storage' with no luck. I've tried to make a Virtual Host with the http.conf file with no luck. Here is the error I'm getting below.

The website encountered an error while retrieving `http://instapics.com:8888/learning-laravel/public/`. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.

Not really sure where to go from here as I've been trying at this for 2 days now.

Comment: By default, MAMP runs on port 80 if I'm not mistaken. Are you sure you want port 8888? Also, instapics.com, is this your localhost? If so, do you see 'something' when you load http://instapics.com:8888 ? Judging from the error you provided, it doesn't seem like it's a permissions error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running it locally with MAMP, it's most likely not a permission error.
You should be able to access it with the url:

localhost:8888/learning-laravel/